# Oci_connect() error while running php in command line

Tags: php, oracle, command-line, windows-server-2008-r2, oracle-call-interface

I am running php script from command line in windows 2008 R2 server with WAMP. I have script that works through browser but when using command line it gives error "Call to undefined function oci_connect()".

PHP script connects to Oracle using oci_connect. Any ideas why OCI-module does not  work through command line? Is it possible to change some setting to achieve success?

Comment: try calling `phpinfo();` from a command-line php script, make sure oracle is enabled in there (probably not), then look up the php.ini path and enable the extension there

Comment: There is these in phpinfo();

--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient10\sdk,shared
--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient10\sdk,shared
--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient11\sdk,shared

So in my acknowledge oracle is enables?

Comment: try to give the full path of your php.ini
`php -c /FULL/PATH/php.ini -f /FULL/PATH/test.php`

Comment: Tryed it. No success. Same error still persist.

Comment: Check your `PATH` settings for the Oracle client libraries (use `where oci*`). They are required for the OCI extension to work. At a guess I would say they are correctly defined for the account running your web server, but not for the account under which you are running your command line script.

Comment: Command Where, gives two paths for OCI. C:\Windows\System32\ and c:\instantclient_11_2\. They both are in path (checked using command path). This is checked using same account that command line php is run.

Comment: This is fixed! I noticed that Command Line PHP is running another PHP.ini than WAMP manager opens. In that PHP ini oci was not active. Thank you everyone for your help